# Persisting many related entities

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have a tree-like data structure in my application.

For example, main entity is DraftDoc, it has a child entity DraftEffect. And DraftEffect has its own child entity DraftOffenderCategory.

What is the best strategy for persisting the data to the database?

To collect the whole tree on the front-end side to one big JSON and persist everything at once?
Or to take DraftDoc data (not including related entities) and persist, then take DraftEffect data and persist and so on?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TN_DRAFT_DOCS")
public class DraftDoc implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "DRAFTDOC_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "DRAFTDOC_SEQ", sequenceName = "NT_DRAFT_DOC_SEQ")
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    private Long articleId;
    
    @Column(name = "ARTICLE_VERSION")
    private Long articleVersion;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "TN_DRAFT_R_DOC_EFF", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "doc_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "eff_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<DraftEffect> effects;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TN_DRAFT_EFFECT")
public class DraftEffect {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "DRAFT_EFFECT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "DRAFT_EFFECT_SEQ", sequenceName = "NT_DRAFT_EFFECT_SEQ")
    @Column
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    private Long articleId;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "effect")
    private List<DraftAffection> affections;
    ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TN_DRAFT_AFFECTION")
public class DraftAffection implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3048761786638684368L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "DRAFTAFFECTION_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "DRAFTAFFECTION_SEQ", sequenceName = "NT_DRAFT_AFFECTION_SEQ")
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    private Long articleId;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well it completely depends on your requirement, As you are implementing Draft functionality, it may happen that you are asked to save partial data/or records in the DB,(before final submission ). It may also happen that all the data is saved in one go. So both are valid implementations but depends on what are the asked features around this. If draft needed to be done only on the frontend(which you will obviously loose on page reload or app refresh etc.), then you can plan single go data submission to backend at final submit

Comment: I guess partial saving will fit better then, thank you!